# How to plot a straight line, not a curve, in PineScript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How can I draw a straight line in PineScript starting from the point where the short ema crosses the long ema and extending to the right?

I plot a straight line starting from the point where the short ema cuts the long ema and extending to the right, but the line curves according to the price. I want to plot a straight line extending to the right independent of the price.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `line.new()` for that. This will draw many lines so you may want to delete the old lines.

Something like below:

```
var line l = na

if (ema_cross)
    l := line.new(bar_index, cross_price, bar_index + 1, cross_price, extend=extend.right)
    line.delete(l[1])  // Optional to delete the old lines
```